# How do I find an element with xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to find a "button" and click it but it has no id.
I tried using Xpath and even cssSelector but nothing works.

This are the elements of the button:

```
div style="cursor: grabbing;" title="Approved Forms" onclick="goToForms(0)" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6"
```

I tried this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title=,'Approved Forms')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")).click(); *copy xpath*
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(['title="Approved Forms"'])).click(); *has a sintax errors, not sure how to write it*
```

Comment: You need to validate XPath and CSS before including them into your test scripts. You can use chrome developer tool to verify the CSS and XPath.  [For reading more about XPaths]( http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2020/01/28/mastering-xpath-for-selenium-test-automation-engineers) .  [Free course on Location strategies](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/chapter1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[title='Approved Forms'][onclick^='goToForms']"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='Approved Forms' and starts-with(@onclick, 'goToForms')]"));
  ```

---

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[title='Approved Forms'][onclick^='goToForms']")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title='Approved Forms' and starts-with(@onclick, 'goToForms')]")));
  ```